# Show selected image from gallery with Gridview on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gridview

I want to show selected images from gallery with gridview. 
But, all the tutorial is just get image from project file..
like this..

```
// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
};
```

I coded like there is add button, if users click it, 
user can save name and photo. And if they save it, shows the photo with gridview..
those data would save in sqlite db.
How can I show the image from sqlite?

Comment: What language? Is this Java?

Comment: i am working on android app!